# How are these type of settings interfaces done in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to create a settings view with a couple of switches and a couple of input fields, I can add them directly to the storyboard but I would like to make it look like the picture below but I'm not sure how they are typically done.

Are they UITableViews? If yes, how do you add views such as switches, textFieds etc. to the rows?

Can someone describe the process on how to create these interfaces? I'm not looking for code just the process.

[image]

Comment: The screen shot is a UITableView with static cells. Each cell is "custom" rather than "basic", so you can drag switches, labels, etc onto them.

Comment: Got it, I found the Static Cells option in the attribute inspector. Thanks a lot.